# How to correctly show M:N relationship in conceptual data model?

Tags: data-modeling, entity-relationship, conceptual-model

I usually find everything I need, but there is first time for everything.. :D

I am trying to create a conceptual data model and I dont know how to properly show M:N relationship, which by default should not be included, but still you can assign verbs and directions of abstract entities. So let's say we have "Projects" and we have "Project roles", how do I properly show relationships? Can I have 2 arrows as showed in the picture or do I have to add join table and ?? I can't wrap my head around this..

Thank you so much in advance :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNbt9.png)

Answer (score 1):

A conceptual data (or information) model can be created with a suitable modeling language, such as ER diagrams or UML class diagrams. Both languages have a concept and a visual notation for many-to-many associations (or relationship types). Simply follow their definitions. Since there is no standard for ER diagrams, it's easier/preferable to go with UML.

For showing a many-to-many association between two classes (representing entity types), you draw a connection line and annotate it with an asterisk ("*") at both ends.

Notice that a join table is a database implementation, and not a modeling concept.